# how to cherry-pick commit containing encrypted file?

Tags: git-crypt

I have one repo with encrypted files. I want to move all of them, including commit history into another repo. I c̶a̶n̶n̶o̶t̶ couldn't figure out very long time a way how to do that.

What eventually worked for me is this:

1. `git init`
2. in *old* repo `git-crypt export-key ~/kf`
3. do NOT unlock repo
4. setup encrypted diretories just as in *old* project, commit .gitattributes files.
5. still do NOT unlock repo
6. setup remote repo in .git/cofig, cherry-picking.
7. now unlock the repo `git-crypt unlock ~/kf`, add collaborators.

this worked for me, if there is better way how to do that, please tell me.